# PHP - Is there any way to load AJAX/Javascript generated content after retrieving html with curl?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, curl

### Problem

I am developing a sitemap generator for my website in PHP. When the script crawls my pages it skips over any Javascript(AJAX) generated content(cURL doesnt wait on javascript execution). Therefore the script will not check any of that content.

### Desired solution

I was wondering if there is any way to execute the javascript after curl returns the file content and simply add it to the response string? (Preferably without the use of any external libs as i have never worked with composer before). Thanks in advance

### My current script

Here are some snippets of my current script for context

**getHtml(function to retrieve html)**

```
// Get the html content of a page and return it as a dom object
    public function getHtml($url)
    {
        // Get html from the given page
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        //Load the html and store it into a DOM object
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($data);

        return $dom;
    }
```

*Html is converted to a dom document so i can list anchor tags*

**html on page**

```
            <div id="product-list" class="row product-list">
            </div>

            <nav class="pt-3" aria-label="Page navigation">
                <ul id="pagination-wrapper" class="pagination mx-auto">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="arrow-left" class="page-item">
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="pagination-numbers">
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="arrow-right" class="page-item">
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

*Html content is generated in a javascript function called by the AJAX request*

**html is set in in javascript function**

```
document.getElementById('product-list').innerHTML = productsHTML;
```

EDIT: Source code for the script can be found here: https://github.com/tristangoossens/php-sitemap-generator

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea - wouldn't it be better to perform the sitemap based on the pages your application can offer? For example, in a CMS-based system, such listings should be generated through an enumeration of database records

Comment: If you want to scrape pages with content generated by client-side JavaScript - then the keyword you want to look into, is _headless browser_.

Comment: @NicoHaase I could implement that logic as my webiste works with a database. I had not thought of that solution, as simple as it may sound. Thank you!

Comment: @CBroe I have looked at headless browsers before asking this question but i couldn't figure out how to use any of them for my purposes. I might just generate sitemap entries with my database records but i might look into headless browsers in detail in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Even if the concept of using a headless browser for this sounds good, it introduces tons of possible problems. From my POV, the performance impact of this is the most severe one. This will take way more time than just listing all URLs your application can generate